# Add a button to the timeline to jump

Tags: python, interface, timeline

Want to make a button in Blender which requires to jump in a specific frame and then again jump into another frame according to the requirement.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and try to clarify your question. Make what jump? Is your question how to move to the next keyframe? Is this to make an object jump interactively on the game engine? what do you mean by "according to the requirement"?

Answer (score 4):

All you really need to do is change the [`current frame`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_current) (via `frame_set`).

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
jump = 5 #however many frames you want to jump
C.scene.frame_set(C.scene.frame_current + jump)
```

These few lines will move the playhead 5 frames ahead. That is all it takes to do that. To make the button takes a bit more python.

---

This script creates a property to store how many frames you want to jump. It creates an operator, which does nothing more then the script above. Finally it adds a button and number input to the header of the timeline.

[image: New UI added to the timeline header]

```
import bpy

class FrameOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Jumps from the curent frame the amount set in scene.frame_jump"""
    bl_idname = "frame.jump"
    bl_label = "Frame Jump Operator"

    bpy.types.Scene.frame_jump = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Frame Jump Count", default=5, min=-499999, max=499999, description="Amount to jump from the current frame. Can be negative. Used in bpy.ops.frame.jump()")

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current + bpy.context.scene.frame_jump)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def draw_frame_jump(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    layout = self.layout

    layout.prop(scene, "frame_jump", text="")
    if scene.frame_jump > 0:
        icon = "TRIA_RIGHT_BAR"
    else:
        icon = "TRIA_LEFT_BAR"
    layout.operator("frame.jump", text="Jump " + str(scene.frame_jump) + " Frames", icon=icon)

def register():
    bpy.types.TIME_HT_header.append(draw_frame_jump)
    bpy.utils.register_class(FrameOperator)

def unregister():  
    # remove header menu
    bpy.types.INFO_HT_header.remove(draw_frame_jump)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(FrameOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

A more detailed walk through of this script.
`class FrameOperator` this is where I'm defining the new operator. The doc string (first line triple quoted) is the tooltip. The `bl_idname` is how blender access it, in this case `bpy.ops.frame.jump()`.

The `bpy.types.Scene.frame_jump` line is *very* important. This creates a new integer property, it is this property that hold the amount `bpy.ops.frame.jump()` will use to jump.
The `execute` function is what gets run when the `bpy.ops.frame.jump()` operator is called. It is in here that you can see the same code from the first script.

The `draw_frame_jump` function holds the code that will get added to the timeline header. First I add the property I created earlier `layout.prop(scene, "frame_jump", text="")`. The if statement is just changes the icon in the button. The `layout.operator` line adds the button to run the operator. Notice the first argument "frame.jump" is the same as defined in the bl_idname.

Now we get down to the `register` function. This simply adds the interface code to the timeline header `TIME_HT_header.append(draw_frame_jump)`, and registers the *frame.jump* operator. (Without registering an operator you can not use it in blender.)

Then it is only a matter of adding the bl_info and you have a full blown [addon](https://gist.github.com/David-Bates/d7152d78ce5f30a6f6d2095f2d51301a#file-jump_frames-py).

Comment: Seems like `TIME_HT_header.` does not exist in Blender 2.83. I used `TIME_MT_editor_menus` instead.